# ASP.NET Core: SignalR: BackgroundService: Pass groupname as parameter

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I have an ASP.Net Core SignalR web application that has a background service. I'm trying to implement grouped clients and am having trouble passing a parameter to my backgroundservice in my Startup.cs. Below is my code:

Background Service.cs:

```
public class LiveDataPubSubWorker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IHubContext<LiveDataHub> _liveDataHubContext;
    private readonly string _groupName;
    public LiveDataPubSubWorker(IHubContext<LiveDataHub> liveDataHubContext, string groupName)
    {
        this._liveDataHubContext = liveDataHubContext;
        this._groupName= groupName;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {            
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var eventMessage = new Models.EventMessage($"Id_{ Guid.NewGuid():N}", $"Title_{Guid.NewGuid():N}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
            await _liveDataHubContext.Clients.Group(this._groupName).SendAsync("onMessageReceived", eventMessage, stoppingToken);
            
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddSignalR(hubPotions=> { hubPotions.EnableDetailedErrors = true; });

        services.AddHostedService<LiveDataPubSubWorker>(); //this line is giving me an error saying that it needs a string as a parameter.             
    }
```

In my AddHostedService, I need to pass the hubcontext and group name(a string) as parameters. How do I accomplish that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        GroupName = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DefaultGroup");
    }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; } 
    public string GroupName { get;}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddSignalR(hubPotions=> { hubPotions.EnableDetailedErrors = true; });


        //services.AddHostedService<LiveDataPubSubWorker>();
        services.AddHostedService<LiveDataPubSubWorker>(
            x => new LiveDataPubSubWorker(x.GetRequiredService<IHubContext<LiveDataHub>>(), GroupName)
        );
        
    }
```